# Zyxel P-320W: How to connect to my web server using public IP

Tags: domain-name-system, router, port-forwarding, zyxel

My company's router is Zyxel P-320W and I have a public static IP.
I registered a few domains name and point to this IP address.
I already setup Virtual Hosts and configured port-forwarding to my internal server and it works well. I can connect to all domains from outside

The problem is I cannot connect to my domains from inside
One workaround way is modify `hosts` file to add internal IP for those domains, but my company have many computers and I don't want to setup all PC manually

Comment: I've come across this problem on a few routers, where there simply wasn't a way of configuring the router to allow this configuration that you want.  My solution was replacing the router or adding records to the local dns server.  I can't remember whether it was a Zyxel or not though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split DNS is the solution. Provide the public address to requests from outside the LAN and the local address to requests from inside the LAN. Do NOT go the way of the hosts file. That road is littered with broken systems and insane administrators. As many of us have learned, one small mistake or oversight and you could spend more time sorting out the issue than you can believe possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just configure a local caching/authoritative DNS server to reply with the internal IPs of your domains and use your router as upstream DNS server (forwarder). Then configure all machines to use that DNS server.